# Do not redirect if uri contains a path

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

I redirect traffic to my website for certain countries like this:

```
if ($http_cf_ipcountry != "UK") {
    return 301 https://int.xyz.com;
}
```

Now, how can I grant user access to site if requested uri was pointing to specific location? for instance something like following but in nginx:

```
if ($http_cf_ipcountry != "UK" && !contains($uri, "/resource/image/")) {
    return 301 https://int.xyz.com;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `location` blocks:

```
location /resource/image/ {
    ...
}
location / {
    if ($http_cf_ipcountry != "UK") {
        return 301 https://int.xyz.com;
    }
    ...
}
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for details.